# Syntax error in E4X

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, e4x

I'm doing a Flash project, in it I'm trying to retrieve information from this xml tree, using a for loop:

```
<game playGame="true" name="peopleNames" id="1">
      <category publish="pubTrue" categoryName="guys" categoryNumber="1">
        <word wordName="ross"/>
        <word wordName="chandler"/>
        <word wordName="joey"/>
      </category>
    <category publish="pubTrue" categoryName="girls" categoryNumber="2">
        <word wordName="rachel"/>
        <word wordName="monica"/>
        <word wordName="phoebe"/>
    </category>
</game>
```

I wrote this query to retrieve data:

```
var insQuery4b:String = xmlData.game.(@id=='1').category.(@categoryNumber=='1').(@publish=='pubTrue').word.@wordName[0];
```

But I want to use it in a loop, so instead for the numbers in this query (1, 0) I'll use the index of the loop (i, for example). I wrote different versions of queries, one of them is:

```
var i:Number = 2;
var insQuery4a:String = xmlData.game.((@id=="'") + i + ("'")).category.((@categoryNumber=="'") + i + ("'")).(@publish=='pubTrue').word.@wordName[0];
```

But non of them works... Any suggestions with the syntax of the query?
Thanks.

Comment: You're expected to accept some answer, if there's any correct one

Answer (score 0):

First the `xml` always begin at the root node, so here you don't have to include the **game** node, you have only todo `xmlData.(@id=='1')` ...

So the first query is:

```
var insQuery4b:String = xmlData.(@id=='1').category.(@categoryNumber=='1').(@publish=='pubTrue').word.@wordName[0];
```

For the second query you don't have to add the quote around the variable i, you want to transform `i` as a `String` for your comparison use the `toString` function.
Also if `i` is an `int` use an `int` type instead of a `Number`
Your second example could be :

```
var i:int = 2;
var insQuery4a:String = xmlData.(@id==i.toString()).category.(@categoryNumber==i.toString()).(@publish=='pubTrue').word.@wordName[0];
```

Live example :
http://wonderfl.net/c/ltN2

P.S.
It can work also without forcing the cast to String as the player will implicitly do it but it's nice to make explicit cast type.

Comment: It was pretty easy, but e4x is new for me, so... Thank you very much, works good so far!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is easier than that, you don't need to mess around with those fancy quotes... just use:

```
var i:uint = 2;
var insQuery4b:String = xmlData.(@id==1).category.(@categoryNumber==i).(@publish=='pubTrue').word.@wordName[0];

trace(insQuery4b);
//output: rachel


//the loop (for example)
var l:uint = xmlData.(@id==1).category.length();

for(i=1; i<=l ;i++)
    trace(xmlData.(@id==1).category.(@categoryNumber==i).(@publish=='pubTrue').word.@wordName[0]);

//ouput: 
//ross
///rachel
```

EDIT:

Patrick is right in that you don't need to use the `game` node with the XML data you have shown us. Usually XML data has a parent node `<xml>`, like this:

```
<xml>
  <game ... >
     rest of XML tree here
  </game>
</xml>
```

Is in that case when you'd need `xmlData.game` to jump to the game node.